# Subring / underring / ring below diacritic in Biblatex

Tags: diacritical-mark

I need to write a "subring", "underring", "combining ring below", "U+0325", whatever you call it, under a letter, in my bibtex document. Usually on Latex I use the package `tipa`  and I just have to use `\textsubring{}` or `\r*{}`, but in my `.bib` file, it does not work anymore.
The article I want to cite is :

```
@article{joseph1982,
  title = {The treatment of \textit{*C\textsubring{R}H-} and the Origin of \textit{CaRa-} in Celtic},
  author = {Joseph, L.},
  date = {1982},
  journaltitle = {Ériu},
  volume = {33},
  pages = {31--57},
  keywords = {celtic}
}
```

Normally I should get this :

[image: subring]

I managed to insert the subring by adding `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{325}{\textsubring{}}` in my preambule but it is not perfect since the subring is after the character :
[image: subring]

Here is my full latex heading:

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{tipa}
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{325}{\textsubring{}}
\usepackage{supertabular}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt,
citestyle=authoryear,
bibstyle=authortitle,
style=authoryear-ibid
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[C]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
```

Comment: Can you include a sample citation in your `Biblio.bib` that uses `\textsubring`?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: you mention `bibtex` in the title, but in the code you load `biblatex` with `biber` back-end.

Comment: Yes indeed, my mistake... I use Biblatex, not Bibtex

Comment: You can't use combining characters in `pdflatex`. So inputting `U+0325` will not work.

Comment: The modern solution would be to use LuaLaTeX/XeLaTeX and insert the character directly in Unicode as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R (U+0052)  and COMBINING RING BELOW (U+0325) = R̥

Answer (score 1):

You can call `biber` with the option

```
--decodecharsset=null
```

to disable all conversions into Unicode. The problem is that `\textsubring{R}` gets translated into R followed by the combining character U+0325, but this can't work in `pdflatex` that has no way to cope with such characters.

Doing

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{325}{\textsubring{}}
```

will do nothing sensible: it will just place the ring after the expected character, as you discovered.

You can call `biber` with the option

```
--decodecharsset=null
```

option, that will disable the conversion to Unicode.

If I do it, I get

```
      \field{title}{The treatment of \textit{*C\textsubring{R}H-} and the Origin of \textit{CaRa-} in Celtic}
```

in the generated `.bbl` file and the output is

[image]